# Как отправить RegexHandler из группы? [python-telegram-bot]

Tags: telegram-bot

Пишу бота используя библиотеку `python-telegram-bot`.

Есть кусок кода - `dp.add_handler(RegexHandler('^(Привет)$', com_start, pass_user_data=True))` который позволяет по слову `Привет` запускать функцию `com_start`. Но это работает лишь в личном чате

Если добавить бота в группу и попробовать написать в группе `Привет` - бот данный хэндлер не отработает. Почему?

При этом команды через `CommandHandler` в группе работают, а вот `RegexHandler` - нет

Возможно я что-то упускаю?

Заранее благодарен за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю для самого себя и таких де как я которые в будущем столкнутся с подобной проблемой.

Что бы бот смог отрабатывать сообщения в группах, нужно через @Botfather установить ему значение `/setprivacy` в `disable`